# Python-Need to redirect the console output to a log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am executing multiple "make" files from my python script. A sample script is as follows :

```
print("Calling make file")

call(["make"])
```

and the output will be :

> Calling make file
>
> Starting make
>
> cd src && make distclean
>
> make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/tejas/WLANrepo/src/3rdparty/redis-stable/src' rm -rf
>   redis-server redis-sentinel redis-cli redis-benchmark redis-check-dump
>   redis-check-aof *.o *.gcda *.gcno *.gcov redis.info lcov-html (cd
>   ../deps && make distclean)'

I want the entire output to be redirected to a log file. I tried :

```
class Logger(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open("Buildexec_logfile.log", "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)
```

but this will redirect only those statements that are under "print". But the output of the make file that gets called is not getting redirected.

Python: python 2.7, OS: CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect output of processes executed by python (in your case, `make`). See documentation for [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and specifically, the redirection parameters (`stdin=...`, `stdout=...`, `stderr=...`) of its methods. Depending on your needs you may completely discard subprocess output (`DEVNULL`), or collect it to a variable inside python process (`PIPE`) or send it to another stream.

Comment: I just tried it and there is a strange (maybe not so strange, the module is called subprocess, so they are probably running in different threads) thing happening - I have print before call, though in log file messages are not in this order. Do you think there's a simple way to arrange them the way they should be?

Comment: Well, I just could propose the following explanation: when you run a process, it's run asynchronously and output from bother processes goes to the console completely independently. You could first collect all of a subprocess output waiting its termination, and then send everything to console in an order you need. I could discess the subject more specifically, but I need a code to observe.

Comment: I used `stdout` itself to call the above mentioned class.                              `from conf.script_logging import Logger
sys.stdout = Logger()`                                                                                               A log file is created but only print statements are printed.

Answer (score 0):

To capture regular output of the command we can use the `subprocess.check_output()` function. 
The synchronization is forced because the function must wait for the output 
of the called sub-process, however if it fails (returns the error message you want to capture) you will need to handle the `CalledProcessError` that is raised. Fortunately the `CalledProcessError` exception has an `output` attribute that stored the error message.

```
import subprocess
with open('logfile.log','w') as log:
    for makefile in multiple_makefiles:
        log.write("calling {}".format(makefile)
        try:
            log_info = subprocess.check_output(["make",makefile],stderr=STDOUT)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            log_info = e.output
        log.write(log_info)
```

The `try` will give log_info the output when the make instance exits cleanly 
and the `except` catches the error when it does not. Either way you cant move on until the `log_info` is written to the `log` file, so there should be no issues with synchronization

I would also add that if you are writing this script for utility reasons like:

> Dang. I really need this compiled now and the makefiles that shipped with it aren't working I need to gather the output to debug this
>    Then go ahead and get it finished in whatever way is most useful or the quickest for you

*BUT*

If you are really doing something more like:

> I need a setup script to automate building my software, and I will ship it with the software for the foreseeable future

Then stop, don't re-invent the wheel you are looking for [cmake](http://cmake.org). (and will log output for you as well)

Comment: Hi Ajay, my bad, should have been more clear. I am executing and installing a host of other scripts as well along with make files. I'll try out the first option.

Comment: @Tejas ahh I see, well in that case the general format of this code should be able to help out!

Comment: in the first piece of code, could you please explain the for loop? Why are you creating a list multiple_makefiles?